# What is it called when I say "catch (Exception e) {}" in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am not sure about this answer. I cant find it anywhere. Is it the empty error handling?!

Comment: See also [*Never 'swallow' exceptions in your code*](http://www.pscode.org/javafaq.html#stacktrace).

Comment: It's called an incredibly bad idea ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer IMO though a little too broad, 'an incredibly bad idea' is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've been working a monolithic application for the past 3 years where the previous developer felt it was okay to "consume" most exceptions...without even logging them. I spent half a day yesterday stepping through code trying to find where the application had suddenly decided to stop to find...and empty try/catch...IMHO, it's an incredibly bad idea, cause know I want to kill him :P (and God only knows how many more we're yet to find)

Answer (score 5):

It is known as suppressing the exception, or swallowing the exception. May not be a very good practice, unless commented with a very good reason.

Answer (score 4):

We affectionately call this "eating the exception" at work.  Basically, it means that something bad occurred, and we are burying our head in the sand and pretending it never happened.  At the very least, a good practice is to have a logger.error(e) within that block:

```
try {
   // code here
}
catch (Exception e) { logger.error(e); }
```

so that you will have it recorded somewhere that an exception occurred.

Comment: From all the answers I read here I like this the best because you should never just comment why your swallowing the exception. You need to log an error at the very least!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's simply called an "**empty catch clause**" (or perhaps *silent exception consumption*), and it should generally be avoided (either handle the exception properly or don't try to catch it at all).

Answer (score 2):

This is generally called as ignoring an exception. Other terms used are [Consuming an exception silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921471/why-java-people-frequently-consume-exception-silently), [Eating an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341214/catch-exception-by-class) etc

Answer (score 1):

It's called "broken code".

(if you want to ignore an exception, then *clearly document the reason*.)

Answer (score 1):

From what i know, this means that in fancy talk "Eating the exception", but simply it just stops this specific error from stoping java while its running your code.
Also the "e" part in the

```
    catch (Exception *e*) {}
```

is the "name" for the error object.

if you're still unsure about whats that then read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Answer (score 0):

I call it "exception masking" and it is not good style.  It is best to catch specific exceptions or let them "bubble up".  Masking exceptions will come back to bite you. It is a good idea to have the exceptions bubble up to be appropriately handled.  If the exception "bubbles to the top", a proactive exception handler can be developed to notify the developer or organization that an unexpected exception has occurred.